# Comparing sets of roots for polynom (SAGEMATH)

Tags: set, compare, root, eigenvalue

I am missing something about how to compare list of roots. 
During a small algorithm I need to know  wether a matrix has or not complex eigenvalues. I did the following

```
   A=matrix(QQ,[[1,2,1],[6,-1,0],[-1,-2,-1]]) 
   a=(B.charpoly()).roots(ring= QQ, multiplicities=False)
   b=(B.charpoly()).roots(ring= QQbar, multiplicities=False)
```

then a is the list [-4,0,3] and b is the list [3,0,-4].
I don't get the following :

```
set(a)==set(b)
```

return false while

```
set([-4,0,3])==set([3,0,-4])
```

return true.

Any help, either on the first pb (knowing that a QQ matrix has complex eigenvalues) or on the second would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.
L.